# What is the Easiest way to stop a soundpool of 4 streams

Tags: java, android

What is the Easiest way to stop a soundpool of 4 streams.

```
    mSoundManager.addSound(1, R.raw.svphorn);
    mSoundManager.addSound(2, R.raw.svpphaser);
    mSoundManager.addSound(3, R.raw.svpwail);
    mSoundManager.addSound(4, R.raw.svpyelp);
```

I need a button to stop all sounds playing @ one time.

Comment: Use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse to examine the Java stack trace associated with your "force close". Also, do not create 999 instances of `MediaPlayer`.

Comment: how could i have the MediaPlayer without 999 instances. For example if person clicks on 20 times it needs to play 20 times at concurently.

Comment: @user407754: `MediaPlayer` is not designed for concurrent playback to that extreme. Please use `SoundPool`, in which a single instance can play back concurrent audio clips.

Comment: I have revised Question using SoundPool same error

Comment: I revised question again

Answer (score 1):

mySoundPool.autoPause() would stop/pause all streams that are playing. And they can be resumed by calling mySoundPool.autoResume().